# How to set scroll vertical in PDFView (com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView)

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

I'am trying PDFView of com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView.

I have a ScrollView with several buttons and in the middle of those buttons is the PDFView.

The PDFView is a PDF file with 5 pages.

The problem is when run app,  scrolling to the PDFView I can only see the first page of the PDF file.

How can I scroll until to the PDFView and then also scroll within the PDFView?

Thanks.

Image:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2QkD8wCK_jqX2d0YlFVT2J3X2M

Code:

```
package gmm.formulariogmm;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;


public class PDFViewDemo extends AppCompatActivity {

PDFView pdfView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdfview);

        pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("test.pdf").load();

}
};//Fin
```

Layout:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button4" />

        <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:id="@+id/pdfView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button6" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: were you able to resolve issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Swipe and the set verticle swipe to true.
like this.

```
pdfView.fromAsset(bookName)
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .swipeVerticle(true)
.load();
```

Thanks

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Ok . I add the detail. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
            .defaultPage(pageNumber)
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .enableDoubletap(true)
            .swipeVertical(false)
            .showMinimap(false)
            .onRender(new OnRenderListener() {
             @Override
             public void onInitiallyRendered(int pages, float pageWidth, 
             float pageHeight) {
            pdfview.fitToWidth(); // optionally pass page number
              }
             });
             .onLoad(this)
             .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
            .load();
```